# How to create multiple barcodes from a list? In the code below

Tags: python-3.x, barcode

I am trying to create a script to generate barcodes from a given list. In this case from a .txt file, with each line being a name/input for the barcode. The code is not the cleanest, still a work in progress.

```
from PIL import Image
import barcode
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

options = {
    'dpi': 1100,
    'font_size':15,
    'module_height': 7,
    'text_distance':12.0,
    }

image_path="C:/Users/*/Desktop/Created Barcodes"

textFile= filedialog.askopenfilename()
  
f= open(textFile, "r").readlines()
for i in f:
    lines = [i.strip() for i in f]
    print(lines)
    number = (f"{lines}")

barcode_format = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')

 #Generate barcode and render as image
image_writer = ImageWriter().set_options(options)
image = barcode_format(number, writer=ImageWriter(),)
  
isExist = os.path.exists(image_path)
if not isExist:
    os.mkdir(image_path)
  
 #Save barcode as PNG    
image= image.save(rf"{image_path}/{number}")
```

I am pretty new to python but from what I experimented in the code, I think that I am doing something wrong/missing on the following part:

```
for i in f:
    lines = [i.strip() for i in f]
    print(lines)
    number = (f"{lines}")
```

I tried changing the code and it did print the text but in one line. Which created one gigantic barcode with all the data.

SOLUTION:

I have fixed my issue by changing my code. The new code is as followed:

```
import barcode
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

options = {
    'dpi': 800,
    'font_size':1,
    'module_height': 0.5,
    'module_width': 100.0,
    'text_distance':5.0,
}

try:
    
    image_path= os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'],'Desktop','Generated')

    textFile= filedialog.askopenfilename()
  
    f= open(textFile, "r").readlines()
    
    lines = [i.strip() for i in f]
    
    barcode_format = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
    
    #For Each Line in the .TXT file
    for code in lines:
        image_writer = ImageWriter().set_options(options)
        image = barcode_format(code, writer=ImageWriter(),)
         #Generate barcode and render as image
    
        isExist = os.path.exists(image_path)
        
        if not os.path.isdir(image_path):
            os.mkdir(image_path)
         
         #Save barcode as PNG    
        image= image.save(rf"{image_path}/{code}")
    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "The Barcodes have been generated successfully!")
except :
    messagebox.showerror("ERROR", "The operation could not be completed due to an ERROR try again please!")
```

Comment: avoid wildcard imports:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73698351/is-anyone-know-how-to-connect-tkinter-webcam-to-yolov5/73712541#73712541

Comment: @D.L Thank you for your comment! I found my mistake and adjusted my code in a different way I will update the post.