# How can i represent my picture who are in bytes form in tkinter with a for loop?

Tags: python, tkinter, byte

i struggle to represent my photos which are in bytes form onto tkinter my plan was to have all my data in a dataframe and then represent it on tkinter with a for loop. It works with all the normal data which are strings but not with the photos. Right know i can only represent the last added photo of the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import base64
import io

global df_main


root = Tk()
root.title("Fabric Database")
root.geometry("400x400")
df_main = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/noahk/Documents/Trial.csv")

def upload_file():
    global lol
    global converted_string
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    #with open(file, "rb") as image2string:
    converted_string = base64.b64encode(open(file, "rb").read())
    lol = converted_string.decode("utf-8")

def submit():
    global df_main
    df_main = df_main.append({'Name': str(name.get()), 'Country': str(country.get()), 'Price': str(price.get()), 'Thickness':str(thickness.get()), 'Fabric Example': lol}, ignore_index = True)    
    #query_label = Label(root, text=df_main)
    #query_label.grid(row=12,column=1)
    print(df_main)

def show_pic():
    global img
    b = base64.b64decode(lol)
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(b))
     
    # resize the image and apply a high-quality down sampling filter
    img = img.resize((20, 20), Image.ANTIALIAS)
 
    # PhotoImage class is used to add image to widgets, icons etc
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    pic = Label(table, image=img)
    pic.grid(row=1,column=5)
    
   
def show_table():
    global b
    global img
    global pic
    
    table = Toplevel()
    table.title("Fabric Database")
    table.geometry("400x400")
    shape_x = df_main.shape
    img_list =[]
    for x in range(0,shape_x[0]):
        
        b = base64.b64decode(df_main["Fabric Example"][x])
        img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(b))
         
        # resize the image and apply a high-quality down sampling filter
        img = img.resize((20, 20), Image.ANTIALIAS)
     
        # PhotoImage class is used to add image to widgets, icons etc
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        
        img_list.append(img)
        print(img_list)
        table_name = Label(table, text="Name")
        table_name.grid(row=0,column=0)
        table_Country = Label(table, text="Country")
        table_Country.grid(row=0,column=1)
        table_Price = Label(table, text="Price")
        table_Price.grid(row=0,column=2)
        table_Thickness = Label(table, text="Thickness")
        table_Thickness.grid(row=0,column=3)
        table_Fabric = Label(table, text="Fabric Example")
        table_Fabric.grid(row=0,column=4)
        
        df_name_label = Label(table, text=df_main["Name"][x])
        df_name_label.grid(row=x+2,column=0)
        df_Countrylabel = Label(table, text=df_main["Country"][x])
        df_Countrylabel.grid(row=x+2,column=1)
        df_Pricelabel = Label(table, text=df_main["Price"][x])
        df_Pricelabel.grid(row=x+2,column=2)
        df_Thicknesslabel = Label(table, text=df_main["Thickness"][x])
        df_Thicknesslabel.grid(row=x+2,column=3)
        pic = Label(table, image=str.encode(img_list[x]))
        pic.grid(row=(2+x),column=4)
    
    
    

    
def search():
    search = Tk()
    search.title("Fabric Database")
    search.geometry("400x400")
    
    global name_table
    global country_table
    global price_table
    global thickness_table
    global fabric_example_table
    
    name_table = Entry(search, width=30)
    name_table.grid(row=2, column=0)
    country_table = Entry(search, width=30)
    country_table.grid(row=2, column=1)
    price_table = Entry(search, width=30)
    price_table.grid(row=2, column=2)
    thickness_table = Entry(search, width=30)
    thickness_table.grid(row=2, column=3)
    fabric_example_table = Entry(search, width=30)
    fabric_example_table.grid(row=2, column=4)
    name_label_table = Label(search, text="Name")
    name_label_table.grid(row=1, column=0)
    country_label_table = Label(search, text="Country")
    country_label_table.grid(row=1, column=1)
    price_label_table = Label(search, text="Price")
    price_label_table.grid(row=1, column=2)
    thickness_label_table = Label(search, text="Thickness")
    thickness_label_table.grid(row=1, column=3)
    fabric_example_label_table = Label(search, text="Fabric example")
    fabric_example_label_table.grid(row=1, column=4)
    
    global search_btn
    search_btn = Button(search, text="Search", command=search_table)
    search_btn.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=10,padx=10,ipadx=120)
    

def search_table():
    stdf = df[(df["Name"]==name_table) & (df["Country"]==country_table) & (df["Price"]==price_table)&(df["Thickness"]==thickness_table)&(df["Fabric Example"]==fabric_example_table)]
    stdf_label = Label(search, text=stdf)
    stdf_label.grid(row=12,column=1)
    
    
    
global name
global country
global price
global thickness
global fabric_example

name = Entry(root, width=30)
name.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=(10,0))
country = Entry(root, width=30)
country.grid(row=1, column=1)
price = Entry(root, width=30)
price.grid(row=2, column=1)
thickness = Entry(root, width=30)
thickness.grid(row=3, column=1)
fabric_example = tk.Button(root, text='Upload Files', 
   width=20,command = lambda:upload_file())
fabric_example.grid(row=4, column=1)



show_btn = Button(root, text="Press", command=show_pic)
show_btn.grid(row=7,column=2)

#create text box labels
name_label = Label(root, text="Name")
name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(10,0))
country_label = Label(root, text="Country")
country_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
price_label = Label(root, text="Price")
price_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
thickness_label = Label(root, text="Thickness")
thickness_label.grid(row=3, column=0)
fabric_example_label = Label(root, text="Fabric example")
fabric_example_label.grid(row=4, column=0)

delete_box = Entry(root, width=30)
delete_box.grid(row=9,column=1,pady=5)
delete_box_label=Label(root, text="Select Row ID")
delete_box_label.grid(row=9,column=0, pady=5)

#Create Submit Button


submit_btn = Button(root, text="Add to Database", command=submit)
submit_btn.grid(row=5,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=10,padx=10,ipadx=105)



query_btn = Button(root, text="Show Table", command=show_table)
query_btn.grid(row=7,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=10,padx=10,ipadx=120)
'''

delete_btn = Button(root, text="Delete Column", command=delete)
delete_btn.grid(row=10,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=10,padx=10,ipadx=120)


update_btn = Button(root, text="Edit Table", command=edit)
update_btn.grid(row=11,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=10,padx=10,ipadx=120)
'''

search_btn = Button(root, text="Search Databank", command=search)
search_btn.grid(row=12,column=0,columnspan=2,pady=10,padx=10,ipadx=120)




root.mainloop()
```

i tried everything, but it seems like the problem may is that it is in byte form, because i could not even represent the photo byte form.

Thanks for your help

Tried showing byte form string of photos and looping through the dataframe and putting it into Tkinter directly or putting the photos into a list and the list into the label and cycling through the list. i was expecting that i can put all photos and information of the dataframe into tkinter to represent the whole table but save the photos in byte form into the dataframe.

Comment: why have you imported tkinter 3 times ?

Comment: avoid wildcard imports:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73698351/is-anyone-know-how-to-connect-tkinter-webcam-to-yolov5/73712541#73712541

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: it is a guess, but I think you need the `img_list` to be a global variable, and not the `img`