# PySimpleGUI Checkbox

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

Idk why, but when i check a checkbox in the menu nothings, happens, but if i close the menu the cheat start. I think that i made some mistakes setting up the checkboxes, but im trying to fix this problem from 3 days now and i can't continue anymore. Can someone help?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import threading
from globals import *
import math
import time
import keyboard

switch = True
rcsonoff = True
r = 255
g = 3
b = 3


def normalizeAngles(viewAngleX, viewAngleY):
    if viewAngleX > 89:
        viewAngleX -= 360
    if viewAngleX < -89:
        viewAngleX += 360
    if viewAngleY > 180:
        viewAngleY -= 360
    if viewAngleY < -180:
        viewAngleY += 360
    return viewAngleX, viewAngleY


def checkangles(x, y):
    if x > 89:
        return False
    elif x < -89:
        return False
    elif y > 360:
        return False
    elif y < -360:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def nanchecker(first, second):
    if math.isnan(first) or math.isnan(second):
        return False
    else:
        return True


layout = [
    # Use a modern font and color scheme
    [sg.Text("External 2.3", font="Helvetica 20", text_color="#d80fc6")],
    # Use tabs to organize the buttons into different categories
    [sg.TabGroup([
        # Tab for aim-related buttons
        [sg.Tab("Aim", [[
            sg.Column(
                # Define the grid layout for the buttons
                [
                    [sg.Checkbox("No Recoil", default=False, key="no_recoil_checkbox")],
                    [sg.Checkbox("TriggerBot", default=False, key="triggerbot_checkbox")]
                ],
                # Set the number of rows and columns in the grid
            )
        ]]),
         # Tab for visual-related buttons
         sg.Tab("Visuals", [[
             sg.Column(
                 # Define the grid layout for the buttons
                 [
                     [sg.Checkbox("Glow", default=False, key="glow_checkbox")],
                     [sg.Checkbox("Chams", default=False, key="chams_checkbox")],
                     [sg.Checkbox("Fov", default=False, key="fov_checkbox")],
                     [sg.Text("Fov Value (MAX 140): "), sg.InputText(key="fov")],
                     [sg.Button("Set FOV Value", button_color=("magenta", "#a9a9a9"))]
                 ],
                 # Set the number of rows and columns in the grid
             )
         ]]),
         sg.Tab("Misc", [[
             sg.Column(
                 [
                     [sg.Checkbox("Bunny Hop", default=False, key="bunny_hop_checkbox")],
                     [sg.Checkbox("Radar Hack", default=False, key="radar_hack_checkbox")],
                     [sg.Checkbox("Show Rank", default=False, key="show_rank_checkbox")],
                     [sg.Checkbox("Third Person", default=False, key="3_person_checkbox")],
                     [sg.Checkbox("No Flash", default=False, key="no_flash_checkbox")]
                 ],
             )
         ]]),
         sg.Tab("LocalPlayer", [[
             sg.Column(
                 [
                     [sg.Text("Player Health:")],
                     [sg.Text(key="Health")],
                     [sg.Text("Armor:")],
                     [sg.Text(key="Armor")],
                     [sg.Text("Enter a new value:")],
                     [sg.InputText(key="NewArmor")],
                     [sg.Button("Update Armor")],
                     [sg.Text("Enter a new money value:")],
                     [sg.InputText(key="Money")],
                     [sg.Button("Update Money")]

                 ],
             )
         ]]),
         # Tab for color-related buttons
         sg.Tab("Color and Debug", [[
             sg.Column(
                 # Define the grid layout for the sliders
                 [
                     [sg.Button("Debug", button_color=("magenta", "#a9a9a9"))],
                     [sg.Text("Enter the glow color values:")],
                     [sg.Text("Red:"), sg.InputText(key="Red")],
                     [sg.Text("Green:"), sg.InputText(key="Green")],
                     [sg.Text("Blue:"), sg.InputText(key="Blue")],
                     [sg.Button("Set Glow Color")]
                 ],
                 # Set the number of rows and columns in the grid
             )
         ]])
         ]])]
]

window = sg.Window("Buck3ts41", layout, element_justification="center")


def debug():
    while True:
        print("crossID ", crosshairID)
        print("corssTeam ", crosshairTeam)
        print("LocalPlayer ", player)
        print("LocalTeam ", localTeam)
        print("GlowManager ", glow_manager)
        print("GetTeam ", getTeam)
        time.sleep(2)


def esp():
    while True:
        try:
            if glow == True:

                for i in range(1, 32):
                    entity = pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + i * 0x10)
                    if entity:
                        entity_hp = pm.read_uint(entity + m_iHealth)
                        entity_team_id = pm.read_uint(entity + m_iTeamNum)
                        entity_dormant = pm.read_uint(entity + m_bDormant)
                        entity_glow = pm.read_uint(entity + m_iGlowIndex)

                        if entity_team_id == 2 and localTeam != 2 and not entity_dormant:  ###TERRORIST###
                            pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x8, float(r))  # R
                            pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0xC, float(g))  # G
                            pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x10, float(b))  # B
                            pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x14, float(255))  # A
                            pm.write_int(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x28, 1)  # START
                        elif entity_team_id == 3 and localTeam != 3 and not entity_dormant:  ###COUNTER###
                            pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x8, float(r))  # R
                            pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0xC, float(g))  # G
                            pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x10, float(b))  # B
                            pm.write_float(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x14, float(255))  # A
                            pm.write_int(glow_manager + entity_glow * 0x38 + 0x28, 1)  # START
        except Exception as err:
            pass
        time.sleep(0.001)

def chamshack():
    if chams:
        rgbt = [255, 0, 0]
        rgbc = [0, 0, 255]
        while True:
            try:
                time.sleep(0.001)
                for i in range(1, 32):
                    entity = pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + i * 0x10)
                    if entity:
                        entity_team_id = pm.read_uint(entity + m_iTeamNum)
                        if entity_team_id == 2:  # terrorist
                            pm.write_int(entity + m_clrRender, (rgbt[0]))  # R
                            pm.write_int(entity + m_clrRender + 0x1, (rgbt[1]))  # G
                            pm.write_int(entity + m_clrRender + 0x2, (rgbt[2]))  # B
                        elif entity_team_id == 3:  # counter
                            pm.write_int(entity + m_clrRender, (rgbc[0]))  # R
                            pm.write_int(entity + m_clrRender + 0x1, (rgbc[1]))  # G
                            pm.write_int(entity + m_clrRender + 0x2, (rgbc[2]))  # B
                        else:
                            pass
            except Exception as err:
                pass
            time.sleep(0.001)


def norcs():
    if no_recoil:
        oldpunchx = 0.0
        oldpunchy = 0.0
        while switch:
            try:
                time.sleep(0.01)
                if rcsonoff:
                    rcslocalplayer = pm.read_uint(client + dwLocalPlayer)
                    rcsengine = pm.read_uint(engine + dwClientState)
                    if pm.read_int(rcslocalplayer + m_iShotsFired) > 1:
                        rcs_x = pm.read_float(rcsengine + dwClientState_ViewAngles)
                        rcs_y = pm.read_float(rcsengine + dwClientState_ViewAngles + 0x4)
                        punchx = pm.read_float(rcslocalplayer + m_aimPunchAngle)
                        punchy = pm.read_float(rcslocalplayer + m_aimPunchAngle + 0x4)
                        newrcsx = rcs_x - (punchx - oldpunchx) * 2.0
                        newrcsy = rcs_y - (punchy - oldpunchy) * 2.0
                        newrcs, newrcy = normalizeAngles(newrcsx, newrcsy)
                        oldpunchx = punchx
                        oldpunchy = punchy
                        if nanchecker(newrcsx, newrcsy) and checkangles(newrcsx, newrcsy):
                            pm.write_float(rcsengine + dwClientState_ViewAngles, newrcsx)
                            pm.write_float(rcsengine + dwClientState_ViewAngles + 0x4, newrcsy)
                    else:
                        oldpunchx = 0.0
                        oldpunchy = 0.0
                        newrcsx = 0.0
                        newrcsy = 0.0

            except Exception as err:
                pass
            time.sleep(0.001)


def bhop():
    if bunny_hop:
        while True:
            try:
                if keyboard.is_pressed("space"):
                    force_jump = client + dwForceJump
                    player = pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer)
                    on_ground = pm.read_int(player + m_fFlags)
                    if player and on_ground and on_ground == 257:
                        pm.write_int(force_jump, 5)
                        time.sleep(0.08)
                        pm.write_int(force_jump, 4)

            except Exception as err:
                pass
            time.sleep(0.001)


def fovhack():
    if fov:
        while True:
            try:
                player = pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList)
                pm.write_int(player + m_iDefaultFOV, Fov)
            except Exception as err:
                pass
            time.sleep(0.001)


def r5():
    if radar_hack:
        while True:
            try:
                for i in range(1, 32):
                    entity = pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + i * 0x10)
                    if entity:
                        pm.write_uchar(entity + m_bSpotted, 1)
            except Exception as err:
                pass
            time.sleep(0.001)


def trigger():
    if triggerbot:
        while True:
            try:

                # If the crosshair is on an enemy, shoot
                if crosshairID > 0 and crosshairID < 64 and crosshairTeam != localTeam:
                    keyboard.press("attack")
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    keyboard.release("attack")
                time.sleep(0.1)
            except Exception as err:
                pass
            time.sleep(0.001)


def person():
    if third_person:
        switch = 0
        while True:
            try:
                localplayer = pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer)

                if keyboard.is_pressed('z') and switch == 0:
                    pm.write_int(localplayer + m_iObserverMode, 1)
                    switch = 1
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                if keyboard.is_pressed('z') and switch == 1:
                    pm.write_int(localplayer + m_iObserverMode, 0)
                    switch = 0
                    time.sleep(0.5)
            except Exception as err:
                pass
            time.sleep(0.001)


def noflash():
    if no_flash:
        if player:
            flash_value = player + m_flFlashMaxAlpha
            if flash_value:
                pm.write_float(flash_value, float(0))
        else:
            pass


def rank():
    if show_rank:
        ranks = ["Unranked",
                 "Silver I",
                 "Silver II",
                 "Silver III",
                 "Silver IV",
                 "Silver Elite",
                 "Silver Elite Master",
                 "Gold Nova I",
                 "Gold Nova II",
                 "Gold Nova III",
                 "Gold Nova Master",
                 "Master Guardian I",
                 "Master Guardian II",
                 "Master Guardian Elite",
                 "Distinguished Master Guardian",
                 "Legendary Eagle",
                 "Legendary Eagle Master",
                 "Supreme Master First Class",
                 "The Global Elite"]
        for i in range(0, 32):
            entity = pm.read_uint(client.lpBaseOfDll + dwEntityList + i * 0x10)
            if entity:
                entity_team_id = pm.read_uint(entity + m_iTeamNum)
                if entity_team_id:
                    player_info = pm.read_uint(
                        (pm.read_uint(engine.lpBaseOfDll + dwClientState)) + dwClientState_PlayerInfo)
                    player_info_items = pm.read_uint(pm.read_uint(player_info + 0x40) + 0xC)
                    info = pm.read_uint(player_info_items + 0x28 + (i * 0x34))
                    playerres = pm.read_uint(client.lpBaseOfDll + dwPlayerResource)
                    rank = pm.read_uint(playerres + m_iCompetitiveRanking + (i * 4))
                    wins = pm.read_uint(playerres + m_iCompetitiveWins + i * 4)
                    if pm.read_string(info + 0x10) != 'GOTV':
                        print(rank)
                        print(pm.read_string(info + 0x10) + "   -->   " + ranks[rank])
                        print(wins)


global glow, chams, no_recoil, triggerbot, bunny_hop, radar_hack, fov, third_person, no_flash, show_rank

while True:

    event, values = window.read(timeout=100)
    if event == "exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == "__TIMEOUT__":
        # Read the health value of the player
        health = pm.read_uint(player + m_iHealth)

        # Update the displayed health value
        window["Health"].update(str(health))
    if event == "Set Glow Color":
        # Split the input string into a list of strings representing the red, green, and blue values
        r = values["Red"]
        g = values["Green"]
        b = values["Blue"]

            # Convert the strings to integers
        r = int(r)
        g = int(g)
        b = int(b)
    if event == "Update Money":
        # Read the new money value from the textbox
        new_money = values["Money"]

            # Convert the new money value to an integer
        new_money = int(new_money)

            # Write the new money value to the game's memory
        pm.write_int(player + m_iAccountID, new_money)
    if event == "Update Armor":
            # Read the new armor value from the textbox
        new_armor = values["NewArmor"]

            # Convert the new armor value to an integer
        new_armor = int(new_armor)

            # Update the armor value
        pm.write_int(player + m_ArmorValue, new_armor)

            # Update the displayed armor value
        window["Armor"].update(str(new_armor))
    if event == "Set FOV Value":
        Fov = values["fov"]
        Fov = int(Fov)
    if values["glow_checkbox"] == True:
        glow = True
    else:
        glow = False
    if values["chams_checkbox"] == True:
        chams = True
    else:
        chams = False
    if values["bunny_hop_checkbox"] == True:
        bunny_hop = True
    else:
        bunny_hop = False
    if values["fov_checkbox"] == True:
        fov = True
    else:
        fov = False
    if values["radar_hack_checkbox"] == True:
        radar_hack = True
    else:
        radar_hack = False
    if values["triggerbot_checkbox"] == True:
        triggerbot = True
    else:
        triggerbot = False
    if values["3_person_checkbox"] == True:
        third_person = True
    else:
        third_person = False
    if values["no_flash_checkbox"] == True:
        no_flash = True
    else:
        no_flash = False
    if values["show_rank_checkbox"] == True:
        show_rank = True
    else:
        show_rank = False
    if values["no_recoil_checkbox"] == True:
        no_recoil = True
    else:
        no_recoil = False
    if event == "Debug":
        debug()


def start_threads():
    try:
        
        threading.Thread(target=esp, name='esp').start()
        threading.Thread(target=chamshack, name='chamshack').start()
        threading.Thread(target=person, name='person').start()
        threading.Thread(target=rank, name='rank').start()
        threading.Thread(target=norcs, name='norcs').start()
        threading.Thread(target=trigger, name='trigger').start()
        threading.Thread(target=bhop, name='bhop').start()
        threading.Thread(target=r5, name='r5').start()
        threading.Thread(target=noflash, name='noflash').start()
        threading.Thread(target=fovhack, name='fovhack').start()
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Threads have been canceled! Exiting...\nReason: {err}\nExiting...')
        exit(1)


start_threads()
window.close()
```

i really don't know what im i doing wrong, i have decent experience with python but pysimpleGUI is another thing...

Comment: Add option `enable_events=True` to Checkbox element. Didn't check the long code here for any other issue.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but this doesen't seem to work. If you have any other tips please tell me

Comment: avoid wildcard imports:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73698351/is-anyone-know-how-to-connect-tkinter-webcam-to-yolov5/73712541#73712541

Comment: SO many places exceptions are being caught but then never reported. At least print the error instead of "pass". Bugs could be anywhere and you'll never know.