# How can i open a shape in a window?

Tags: python, tkinter, window, shapes

So, i was looking for a way to open a window (to make a game) and i figured out, it needs some shaped decoration, so i was looking in other posts of stack overflow and there were none saying how to make it. anyways i need to make it fit in the selected code i found on some of the posts of stack overflow.

```
from tkinter import *

class Main:
    def __init__ (self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Reminder")
        self.root.geometry("222x222")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    obj = Main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Well, the window did work, but it was kind of tough searching the way how to make a window, since most of the tutorial videos were really bad, so are those underrated web sites claiming they have the solution of that or something, anyways they are weirdos, anyways, moving to the shapes expectation i tried watching some tutorial videos but like last time, they were really bad, so i gived up until i found this website, so can you guys help me out with that.

Comment: "Open a shape in a window" can mean many different things. What do you mean by "a shape"? Are you asking how to draw a rectangle or circle  inside the window? Or as you asking  how to make  non-rectangular root window? Something else?

Comment: Opening a shape that appears in a window.

Comment: @OscarHernandez Look at the `tkinter.Canvas` class. With that, you can easily make different shapes and with some work you can make the shapes interact.

Comment: I suggest looking at https://python-course.eu/tkinter/canvas-widgets-in-tkinter.php for examples of drawing shapes on tkinter.canvas.

Comment: A quick note to avoid wildcard imports:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73698351/is-anyone-know-how-to-connect-tkinter-webcam-to-yolov5/73712541#73712541

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter has a widget named [Canvas](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/canvas.html) that is designed to let you draw shapes. Here's a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main:
    def __init__ (self,root):
        self.root = root

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, background="white")
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 110, 110, outline="black", fill="red")
        self.canvas.create_line(10, 150, 210, 150, fill="green", width=4)
        self.canvas.create_oval(10, 210, 210, 310, outline="blue", fill="yellow")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    obj = Main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to make a game, I highly suggest `pygame` over `tkinter` because `tkinter` is not really suited for stuff like this (although it is possible, quality won't be as good `pygame`).

Nevertheless, if you do still intend to use `tkinter`, you might want to know the limitations first. All shapes will have to "labels" with images in it, so essentially it will be all rectangles.

Click here for a post on [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133856/how-to-add-an-image-in-tkinter) to do that

Comment: The following code on the post wont work.

Comment: I suggest looking at https://python-course.eu/tkinter/canvas-widgets-in-tkinter.php for examples of drawing shapes on tkinter.canvas.

Comment: Instead of appearing, it hides the window somehow.

Comment: You can draw shapes on a canvas. You don’t have to use labels.