# How to assign the click on the right button with change of the prompt?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a total newb when it comes to coding, did some beginner stuff but also wanted to see how difficult it would be to get the simple game going. Truth to be told is that I have no idea how to make a game. I did scrap some code from baunch of things but I am not sure Im following the right path. Please if you could guide me on what to do and maybe what to learn for that project I would be very thankful.

Now onto the game:
It is simple color game.
There is a prompt that states the color (from red, blue, green and yellow) and you have to click on the right colored square. Clicking gives you a point and you try to get most poinst you can in a minute.

My code so far looks something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

user_wins = 0

#window
win = Tk()
win.geometry("500x500")


def on_click():
    label["text"] = Label(win, text=(random.choice(a)), font="consolas 15").pack()


#buttons
button1 = Button(win, text = 'Red', fg='Black', bg='red', height=5, width=10, command= on_click )
button1.place(x=125, y=125)

button2 = Button(win, text = 'Yellow', fg='Black', bg='yellow', height=5, width=10, command= on_click )
button2.place(x=250, y=125)

button3 = Button(win, text = 'Blue', fg='Black', bg='blue', height=5, width=10, command= on_click )
button3.place(x=125, y=250)

button4 = Button(win, text = 'Green', fg='Black', bg='green', height=5, width=10, command= on_click )
button4.place(x=250, y=250)

#text description
Label(win, text="Press the right color", font='Consolas 15').pack()

#what to press
a = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]
label = Label(win, text=(random.choice(a)), font="consolas 15").pack()

#press 


#score
    

#score counting


#timer
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, this is not quite how SO works. Usually, people post a concrete question and the community points out what's wrong. In this case, it's hard to tell what the question is about. What's not working as expected and what did you expect?

Comment: avoid wildcard imports:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73698351/is-anyone-know-how-to-connect-tkinter-webcam-to-yolov5/73712541#73712541

Answer (score 0):

Pass the color of the button as a parameter to `on_click()`, so it can check if that matches the color in the label.

When you change the text of the label you don't need to call `Label()` again. Just get another random choice and assign that to `label["text"]`.

```
def on_click(color):
    global user_wins
    if color == label["text"]:
        user_wins += 1
    label["text"] = random.choice(a)

#buttons
button1 = Button(win, text = 'Red', fg='Black', bg='red', height=5, width=10, command= lambda: on_click('red') )
button1.place(x=125, y=125)

button2 = Button(win, text = 'Yellow', fg='Black', bg='yellow', height=5, width=10, command= lambda: on_click('yellow') )
button2.place(x=250, y=125)

button3 = Button(win, text = 'Blue', fg='Black', bg='blue', height=5, width=10, command= lambda: on_click('blue') )
button3.place(x=125, y=250)

button4 = Button(win, text = 'Green', fg='Black', bg='green', height=5, width=10, command= lambda: on_click('green') )
button4.place(x=250, y=250)
```

Comment: line 13, in on_click
    if color == label["text"]:
                ^^^^^
NameError: name 'label' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Label'?

Comment: @toyotaSupra The script has `label = Label(win, text=(random.choice(a)), font="consolas 15").pack()`