# ctypes,python3.9,access violation writing,Linked list reference return wrong

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes

i have some dumb questions about ctypes.

here is my code:

```
import ctypes as cpp
from PositionDef import *
from PositionFunc import *

Lib = cpp.cdll.LoadLibrary('Position.dll')

#init handle
Handle = cpp.c_void_p()
rlt = Lib.API_Initial(cpp.byref(Handle)) # OK

#get marker
markerSt = T_MarkerInfo()
Lib.SetAcquireData(Handle,0)
rlt = Lib.GetMarker(Handle, cpp.byref(markerSt)) # OK

#mapping marker with other point
res = T_ToolDataResult()
Lib.MappingPointSetsForMarkerSpaceReg.argtypes = [cpp.c_void_p, 
                                                          cpp.POINTER(T_MarkerInfo), 
                                                          cpp.POINTER(T_ToolDataResult), 
                                                          cpp.c_int]
Lib.MappingPointSetsForMarkerSpaceReg.restype = cpp.c_int

rlt = Lib.MappingPointSetsForMarkerSpaceReg(Handle,cpp.byref(markerSt),cpp.byref(res),0) # NOT OK
```

here is the MappingPointSetsForMarkerSpaceReg defination in c++:

```
int MappingPointSetsForMarkerSpaceReg(Handle p, T_MarkerInfo & marker, T_ToolDataResult * plist, int minimumMatchPts)
```

T_ToolDataResult is defined:

```
    struct T_ToolDataResult
    {
        E_ToolType type;    
        bool validflag;             
        char  toolname[200];    
        float MeanError;    
        float Rms;  

        float rotationvector[3];    
        float Qoxyz[4];             
        float Rto[3][3];            
        float Tto[3];           

        float OriginCoor[3];        
        float tooltip[3];       
        float toolmid[3];   
        float toolCstip[3];     
        float toolCsmid[3];         
        std::vector<int>toolptidx;  
        T_ToolDataResult* next;
    };
```

and i rewrite in python:

```
class T_ToolDataResult(ctypes.Structure):
T_ToolDataResult._fields_ = [
    ('type', E_ToolType),
    ('validflag', ctypes.c_bool),
    ('toolname', ctypes.c_char * 200),
    ('MeanError', ctypes.c_float),
    ('Rms', ctypes.c_float),
    ('rotationvector', ctypes.c_float * 3),
    ('Qoxyz', ctypes.c_float * 4),
    ('Rto', (ctypes.c_float * 3) * 3),
    ('Tto', ctypes.c_float * 3),
    ('OriginCoor', ctypes.c_float * 3),
    ('tooltip', ctypes.c_float * 3),
    ('toolmid', ctypes.c_float * 3),
    ('toolCstip', ctypes.c_float * 3),
    ('toolCsmid', ctypes.c_float * 3),
    ('toolptidx', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)),
    ('next', ctypes.POINTER(T_ToolDataResult))
    ]
```

if MappingPointSetsForMarkerSpaceReg worked well, result will be stored in res. And i can read my desired information in T_ToolDataResult.

but i get Error message:
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x000000000000

any ideas? thx

i have tried:

```
toolptidx = (ctypes.c_int * 200)() 
res.toolptidx = ctypes.cast(toolptidx, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
```

and still doesn't work.

Comment: It's `ctypes`, not `cpptypes`.  The functions you call and structures you access have to be C-compatible.  `std::vector<int>toolptidx;` isn't supported.  Also the tag is [tag:ctypes] for Python, not [tag:ctype] (for VB).  I fixed it.

Comment: avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73698351/is-anyone-know-how-to-connect-tkinter-webcam-to-yolov5/73712541#73712541)