# i cant get variable from another script in real time

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

i was trying to get variable progress_percent from another script in real time but its not working
its example of may code

main.py

```
# Tkinter Imports
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

# other imports
import os
from Converter import *
from threading import Thread


# functions
# file explorer window
def browseFiles():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir="/",
        title="Select a File",
        filetypes=(("all files", "*.*"), ("Text files", "*.txt*")),
    )
    filename = filename.replace(" ", "_")
    # Change label contents
    label_file_explorer.configure(text="File Opened: " + filename.replace(" ", "_"))
    global fileNoExt
    fileNoExt = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]


def ConvertCommand():
    convertingThread = Thread(target=convert, args=(filename, fileNoExt, OutputType))
    convertingThread.start()


# Options
root = Tk()
root.title("AsterConv")
root.geometry("900x900")
root["bg"] = "#011627"

# creating Elements
label_file_explorer = Label(
    root, text="File Explorer using Tkinter", width=40, height=4, fg="blue"
)

button_explore = Button(root, text="Browse Files", command=browseFiles)

button_exit = Button(root, text="Exit", command=exit)

OutputType = StringVar(root)
OutputType.set("mp4")  # default value
ConvertType = OptionMenu(root, OutputType, "mp4", "mkv", "mkv", "webm")

ConvertBtn = Button(root, text="Browse Files", command=ConvertCommand)

ProgressBar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal", mode="determinate", length=280)
ProgressBar["value"] = progress_percent
# placing elements
label_file_explorer.grid(column=0, row=0)

button_explore.grid(column=0, row=1)

button_exit.grid(column=0, row=2)

ConvertType.grid(column=1, row=0)

ConvertBtn.grid(column=1, row=1)

ProgressBar.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

and it is the converting code
i need to get variable from this py file and give it to main py
converter.py

```
import subprocess as sp
import shlex
import json
from threading import Thread
import time



def convert(filename, fileNoExt, OutputType):
    OutputFile = fileNoExt + "." + OutputType.get()

    def progress_reader(procs, q):
        while True:
            if procs.poll() is not None:
                break

            progress_text = procs.stdout.readline()

            if progress_text is None:
                break

            progress_text = progress_text.decode("utf-8")

            if progress_text.startswith("frame="):
                frame = int(progress_text.partition("=")[-1])
                q[0] = frame

    data = sp.run(
        shlex.split(
            "ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 -of json "
            + filename
        ),
        stdout=sp.PIPE,
    ).stdout
    dict = json.loads(data)
    tot_n_frames = float(dict["streams"][0]["nb_read_packets"])

    process = sp.Popen(
        shlex.split(
            "ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -i "
            + filename
            + " -progress pipe:1 "
            + OutputFile
        ),
        stdout=sp.PIPE,
    )

    q = [0]
    progress_reader_thread = Thread(target=progress_reader, args=(process, q))
    progress_reader_thread.start()

    while True:
        if process.poll() is not None:
            break

        time.sleep(1)

        n_frame = q[0]
        global progress_percent 
        progress_percent = (n_frame / tot_n_frames) * 100
        print(f"Progress [%]: {progress_percent:.2f}")

    process.stdout.close()
    progress_reader_thread.join()
    process.wait()

    # print("converting " + filename + " to " + OutputFile)
```

how i can do that?
global is not working, i was trying do it with functions , threads and other, but its doesnt work
i was trying to use many other libraries but it doesnot work
who can help me to fix this error

Comment: avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73698351/is-anyone-know-how-to-connect-tkinter-webcam-to-yolov5/73712541#73712541)

Comment: When the line `ProgressBar["value"] = progress_percent` is executed, `progress_percent` inside `converter` module has not been created yet because `convert()` has not been executed.

Comment: yes i know it, how i can fix that? how to get variable from convert() in real time and give it to main.py.        
I tried to create a variable outside the function and then change it inside the function, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix the problem, I added the queue library and with the help of it I transfer information
i added this to convert.py

```
import queue
que = queue.Queue()

que.put(progress_percent)
```

and this to main.py

```
def Progressbar():
    while True:
        # print(que.get())
        ProgressBar["value"] = que.get()
        print(ProgressBar["value"])
        time.sleep(1)
```