# Stuck on getting an override button to work as intended in packet tracer

Tags: python

The override button just doesn't want to work, the automated side is fine.

```
from gpio import *
from time import *

# Define constants
TEMPERATURE_SENSOR_PORT = 0
BUTTON_PORT = 1
HEATER_PORT = 2
LCD_PORT = 3

class GreenhouseController():
    def __init__(self):
        # Set initial states
        self.heater_on = False
        self.user_override = False
        
    def button_event_handler(self):
        # Handles button events
        if digitalRead(BUTTON_PORT) == HIGH:
            self.user_override = not self.user_override
            self.update_heater_state()

    def update_heater_state(self):
        # Update heater state based on temperature or user override
        temperature = self.get_temperature()

        if self.user_override:
            digitalWrite(HEATER_PORT, HIGH)
        else:
            if temperature <= 5:
                self.heater_on = True
            else:
                self.heater_on = False

        digitalWrite(HEATER_PORT, HIGH if self.heater_on else LOW)
        
    def get_temperature(self):
        # Gets temperature from the sensor
        analog_value = analogRead(TEMPERATURE_SENSOR_PORT)
        temperature = ((float(analog_value) / 1024) * 201) - 100
        return temperature

    def update_lcd(self, temperature, heater_state):
        # Update the LCD with temperature and heater status
        message = 'Temp: {:.1f} {}C\nHeater: {} '.format(
            temperature, chr(176), "On" if heater_state else "Off")
        customWrite(LCD_PORT, message)

    def main(self):
        print('Starting Greenhouse Temp...')
        # Add the button event detection
        add_event_detect(BUTTON_PORT, self.button_event_handler)

        while True:
            # Update heater state, Get temperature and Update LCD
            self.update_heater_state()
            temperature = self.get_temperature()
            self.update_lcd(temperature, self.heater_on)

            sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    greenhouse_controller = GreenhouseController()
    greenhouse_controller.main()
```

Comment: The text box is throwing hurdles at you because you're supposed to give us some useful information and context. A context-less code dump makes it quite difficult for anyone to answer your question, since it's not clear what you want, what you've already tried, what kind of errors you're getting, what platform you're programming for, etc... Pleas, consider having a look at [ask].

Comment: whilst wildcard imports are allowed, for clarity it is best to avoid then:
[wildcard imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73698351/is-anyone-know-how-to-connect-tkinter-webcam-to-yolov5/73712541#73712541)

Comment: sorry i was frustrated enough with the code by the time i came here and then the text box was having issues with indents after passing it through python beautify, i have tried and changed it from what i posted but still cant get the override button to work, it is for packet tracer in an environment where an mcu is automatically controlling a heater, but should be able to be manually turned on by the button, the automation works fine just not the button and as it is now there are no errors being generated

Comment: no worries mate. maybe you can [edit] your question to include this information? It would also be good to mention what **Cisco Packet Tracer** is, and that you are **simulating** a raspberry pi (*not an MCU*), and that you do not have access to a "normal" Python environment. All of this is critical information if you want an answer. In the mean time, I'll write up what I think may be the issue, based on some assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find any documentation for the Cisco Packet Tracer `gpio` module, however, I assume that it is supposed to mimic the [RPi.GPIO](https://pypi.org/project/RPi.GPIO/) module, so that code written for the simulation can be easily ported to the real hardware.

With that assumption in mind, I would refer you to the examples for that module (specifically to the paragraphs about [Interrupts and Edge Detection](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/)). The API documentation is not great, but it can be seen that the second argument of the `GPIO.add_event_detect` function should be either `GPIO.RISING`, `GPIO.FALLING` or `GPIO.BOTH` (depending on the event you want to detect), **not** the callback, which should be the third argument. In fact, this function takes up to four arguments, in the following order :

> `GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=200)`

In your case, you want to detect a rising edge (since you're looking for a HIGH signal), and this way your callback does not `GPIO.digitalRead`.